# Is there any way to use '.' key instead of ';' key to repeat inline search ('f' key) in vim

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I'm new to vim and I learned <kbd>f</kbd> key can be repeated by <kbd>;</kbd> key today.

However I've already use <kbd>;</kbd> key as Leader.
Is there any way to use <kbd>.</kbd> key instead?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can map <kbd>.</kbd> to do the job of <kbd>;</kbd>:

```
nnoremap . ;
```

However, then you lose the function of <kbd>.</kbd> (repeat the last change), unless you remap *that*.

Risking to sound preachy, but it will be long-term much better for you to adapt to Vim, than to try to adapt Vim to you — at least until you are no longer a beginner. In this case, for example, I'd say <kbd>.</kbd> (repeat last command) is a much more important function than <kbd>;</kbd> (repeat last <kbd>f</kbd>-search) is, especially since leader can be <kbd>\</kbd> as is the default, or <kbd>Space</kbd>, as keys with much less to lose.

Comment: Thx for your advice! (:  I've returned back to default ' \ '. However, I still guess whether there can be a script which makes ' . ' key just handle all repeats, no matter "search" or "last change" ...

Comment: Why would that be useful, though? For example, a very common pattern I use is to search for something using `/`, then make a change using `c`; after that, `n` to go to the next occurence and `.` to repeat the change if i wish, cycle, repeat. If "repeat search" and "repeat change" were the same key, I couldn't do that. It would also be contextual in a very fiddly way. Having separate dedicated commands is definitely superior.

Comment: In my opinion, f-search is  a "small" search so using ' . ';  /-search is a "big" search so using 'n'. Anyway, your advice is right. I should first adapt to vim than making vim adapt to me